# What are the relation and difference between `sysconf()` and `getrlimit()`?

Tags: c, linux, limit, ulimit

What are the relation and difference between `sysconf()` and `getrlimit()`?

Do they provide two different ways to report the limits of the same resources?

When shall we use which?

Thanks.

I have found two contradictory comments on the two functions:

From http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/whats-difference-sysconf-rlimit-955656.html

> If I remember correctly, the sysconf() stuff cannot be changed by a
> process (i.e.) they are configured at a kernel level and need a
> recompile of the operating system kernel and/or C libraries to change
> them. You can only read those values, but not alter them at runtime.
>
> With setrlimit()/getrlimit(), you can read and change the values
> (within reason) of certain resources at runtime. For instance, you can
> call setrlimit() to set the max. core dump size of a process, which is
> useful if a process crashed often and you don't want to fill your hard
> disk up with large files.
>
> The parameters you can read/set with rlimit are different from the
> parameters that you can read with sysconfig(). They deal with
> different system knobs.
>
> sysconf() and getrlimit() return the values of different resource settings (**without overlap**), so you call the appropriate one depending on what information your program seeks.

But from APUE:

> For example, we can use the **ulimit** command built into the Bourne-again
> shell to change the maximum number of ﬁles our processes can have open
> at one time. This generally  requires  special  (superuser)
> privileges  if  the  limit  is  to  be  effectively unlimited.  But
> once  set  to  inﬁnite, **sysconf** will  report LONG_MAX as  the  limit
> for OPEN_MAX. A program that relies on this value as the upper bound
> of ﬁle descriptors to close, as shown in Figure 2.17, will waste a lot
> of time trying to close 2,147,483,647 ﬁle descriptors, most of which
> aren’t even in use.
>
> Systems that support the XSI option in the Single
> UNIX Speciﬁcation will provide the **getrlimit**(2) function  (Section
> 7.11).  It can  be  used  to  return  the  maximum number of descriptors that a process can have open. With it, we can detect that
> there is no conﬁgured upper bound to the number of open ﬁles our
> processes can open, so we can avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`sysconf` is a general-purpose function to get value of many different **system configuration** variables, not only resources limits. Some represent system-wide limits. `sysconf` have no setting function counterpart (some of these values are not dynamic). All of these values shall not change across two calls in the same process (see exception below).

`getrlimit` is a function to get value of **resource limits**. Its setting counterpart is `setrlimit`(on which there can be some restrictions).

Both are defined by POSIX, and standard says nothing about overlapping except for `OPEN_MAX` which may change during process lifetime.